# Generation of graphics on a website

Tags: web-browser, graphs

A while ago, I improved a tutorial for creating RC hovercraft skirts. To summarize, we start from the vertical cut of the skirt (bottom left corner), and a projection of points is carried out at a chosen angle (here 45 °) : [link to the tutorial](https://www.diy-hovercraft.com/theory/custom-bag-skirt).

[image]

I would like to make the generation of these graphs easier, for myself and others. Ideally, the user would only have to enter a few numbers into the website to get the result.

My question is : what software, or JS extension maybe, could I use ? I have a few programming skills so I wouldn't be afraid of programming something by myself. It's just that I really don't know where to start. Thanks in advance !

Comment: If there is no requirement that the image should be printable in a certain size I would try to generate an SVG image via JavaScript. If it should be printable in a certain size I would prefer an PDF file (not sure how to generate a PDF the easy way in your case).

Comment: You can do this without any additional library. You can simply add a canvas element and draw your lines. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp is a good starting point.
https://stackoverflow.com/ may be a better place for this question.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. HTML canvas seems to be the right tool for me and I will give it a try. Thanks again.